# Implement trait for type with nested bound

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to implement a trait for a type implementing a generic trait with a bound on the inner type. The compiler shows me an error. Are there any known workarounds for this?

### Code

```rust
trait MyTrait1 {}
trait MyTrait2 {}
trait MyTrait3<T> {}

impl <T: MyTrait1, U: MyTrait3<T>> MyTrait2 for Vec<U> {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ef9e836313f23810c24985aedf7ca64)

### Error:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/lib.rs:5:7
  |
5 | impl <T: MyTrait1, U: MyTrait3<T>> MyTrait2 for Vec<U> {}
  |       ^ unconstrained type parameter

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0207`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0207`

Comment: no context == read compiler explanation

Comment: The compiler cannot deduce what `T` is when seeing if `Vec<U>` implements `MyTrait2`. You may think it can deduce this by the `U: MyTrait3<T>` bound but `U` can implement `MyTrait3` for *multiple* types of `T`.

Comment: If `MyTrait3` can only ever be implemented for a single type `T` for each type it is implemented for, you should turn `T` into an associated type rather than a type parameter. The impl can then be written as `impl <U: MyTrait3> MyTrait2 for Vec <U> {}`, i.e. you simply omit the associated type. This will allow the assoicated type to be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to do but as @Sven Marnach said you can use associated types. That way it will not be unconstrained because only one type can be associated with the trait implementation.

```rust
trait MyTrait1 {}
trait MyTrait2 {}
trait MyTrait3 {
    type AssociatedType;
}

impl<T, U> MyTrait2 for Vec<U>
where
    U: MyTrait3<AssociatedType = T>,
    T: MyTrait1,
{
}
```